# Changing R output object names with function arguments

Tags: r, function, arguments

I'm new to R, so please excuse (and correct) me if my language is imprecise.

I have written a program to load data, create a contingency table (using xtabs), run some external functions on it, and output results tables. I've run the code on my full data set, and would like to run the same code on subsets of my data. I've wrapped the code up as a function, and would like to be able to be able to pass the *name of the subset* (SUBNAM) and the *subset expression* (SUBEXP) as arguments in the function call something like:

```
HCACC <- function (SUBNAM, SUBEXP) {  
   CM.SUBNAM <- as.matrix(
      xtabs(~HC_map+HC_obs, data=VVD
      , drop.unused.levels=FALSE, sparse=TRUE
      , subset=(SUBEXP)
      ) )

   AKw.SUBNAM <- kw(CM.SUBNAM, wtHC)
   USER.SUBNAM <- as.data.frame(AKw.SUBNAM$user.wa)
   write.csv(HCACC.SUBNAM, file="HCACC.SUBNAM.csv", row.names=TRUE)
}

HCACC(2013, Year == 2013)
HCACC(JMDR, Observer == "JMDR")
```

(the last three lines are examples of where I want the SUBNAM, there are actually 40 instances)

I would like to end up with CM.2013, CM.JMDR, etc. without having to copy/paste & find/replace the code repeatedly.

It seems like there must be a way to do this, but the way I tried it didn't work, and my googling didn't turn anything up (but I suspect I may have been asking the wrong questions). Any tips or pointers would be appreciated.

`*EDIT*` To clarify, I am open to other methods of passing the subset name and expression in to the function other than as arguments. I just want to be able to repeat the analysis/code a bunch of times on different subsets and have output named accordingly. Thanks for your insights!

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the xtabs and kw functions but I think your SUBEXP expression has to be a character. 'Year == 2013' isn't exactly an argument you can pass to your function (I don't think). You might have to pass it as a string and then use `eval(parse(text = SUBEXP))`. I'm sorry if I misinterpreted your question.

Comment: I doubt you will get any answers unless you show people your input data and give them a `dput()` of it. Ask yourself if someone showed you the function you posted - could you decipher it without seeing the data?

Comment: Just to move you in the right direction, when you pass something like `Year == 2013` or `Observer == "JMDR"` in a function (or elsewhere), what you are actually passing is a logical vector whose values are "Is each value of the variable Year equal to 2013".  You might mean to use the function `quote` or `expression`, but then it gets pretty gritty.  There are other ways to accomplish the same task, but it is not altogether clear what your goal is here.

Comment: You could probably make it work by using `VVD$Year == 2013` instead, but that's not a great solution. The real problem here is that you've hard coded too much stuff into your function. Rather than hard code `data = VVD`, just skip the subset argument and pass your function the subset of the data you want. That's much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

First,  it looks like there is an error (typo) in your code. You created the data frame USER.SUBNAM, but try to write out the non-existent HCACC.SUBNAM. Also,  your comments say that you want that you want the file names CM.2013 and CM.JMDR but your code seems to be trying for HCACC.2013 and HCACC.JMDR.

It looks like the only place that you actually need to use SUBNAM is in the output file name. All of the variables in your function are temporary variables and do not need to have different names each time that you call the function. So instead, I think that you want something like:

```
    HCACC <- function (SUBNAM, SUBEXP) {  
       CM <- as.matrix(xtabs(~HC_map+HC_obs, data=VVD, 
        drop.unused.levels=FALSE, sparse=TRUE,
        subset=(SUBEXP)
          ) )

       AKw <- kw(CM, wtHC)
       HCACC <- as.data.frame(AKw$user.wa)
       write.csv(HCACC, file= paste("HCACC.", SUBNAM, ".csv", sep=""),  
        row.names=TRUE)
    }

    HCACC(2013, Year == 2013)
    HCACC(JMDR, Observer == "JMDR")
```